# How to connect to remote Cassandra server through pyspark for write operation?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect to remote Cassandra server through pyspark, but it is not performing write operation in Cassandra while running cronjob. The same code works on the server on jupyter notebook, but not through cronjob.

`os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--master local[*] pyspark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:2.5.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 pyspark-shell --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions'

from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "keyspace_name")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

Data_to_Write.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode('append').options(table="tablename",keyspace="keyspace_name").save()`

I see this error in the cassandra logs : ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2020-08-05 09:24:36,606 OutboundConnectionInitiator.java:373 - Failed to handshake with peer xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042(xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042) org.apache.cassandra.net.Crc$InvalidCrc –

Comment: Are you seeing any error message?

Comment: I see this error in the cassandra logs :
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2020-08-05 09:24:36,606 OutboundConnectionInitiator.java:373 - Failed to handshake with peer xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042(xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042)
org.apache.cassandra.net.Crc$InvalidCrc